# <use> tag inside <svg> throws off height

Tags: css, svg

I have a use tag that references an inline svg as shown below:

```
<svg class="icon icon-handshake mp-stat-block__stat-icon--no-value" viewBox="0 0 85 85" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <use xlink:href="#icon-handshake"></use>
</svg>
```

The icon that is referenced is positioned at the top of the SVG instead of centred. This doesn't happen when the svg is used without the  tag.

How can this be fixed.

Codepen for reference

```css
.icon-handshake {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.mp-stat-block.orange {
  background-color: #fdebe2;
}

.mp-stat-block {
  background-color: #e3f5f6;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.mp-container {
  padding: 0 1.8rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 122rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mp-stat-block .mp-stat-block__container .mp-stat-block__stat {
  margin: 0 3% 3rem;
}

.mp-stat-block .mp-stat-block__container .mp-stat-block__stat-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 9.4rem;
  height: 9.4rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mp-stat-block .mp-stat-block__container .mp-stat-block__stat-circle:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0.5rem solid #a9dadc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mp-stat-block .mp-stat-block__container .mp-stat-block__stat-circle .mp-stat-block__stat-info {
  position: absolute;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.mp-stat-block.orange .mp-stat-block__stat-circle .icon {
  color: var(--theme-primary);
  /* line-height: 10rem; */
}

.mp-stat-block .mp-stat-block__container .mp-stat-block__stat-circle .icon {
  width: 3.4rem;
  height: 3.4rem;
  color: #2da5b0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  top: .25ex;
  fill: currentColor;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.mp-stat-block .mp-stat-block__container .mp-stat-block__stat-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  max-width: 20.2rem;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-align: center;
  color: #343a40;
  text-transform: none;
  margin: 1rem auto 0;
}

.mp-stat-block .mp-stat-block__container .mp-stat-block__stat-cap {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #343a40;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1rem auto 0;
  max-width: 20.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="mp-stat-block">
  <div class="mp-stat-block__container">
    <div class="mp-stat-block__stat">
      <div class="mp-stat-block__stat-circle">
        <div class="mp-stat-block__stat-info">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            width="85" height="85" viewBox="0 0 85 85"
            class="icon icon-handshake mp-stat-block__stat-icon--no-value"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-handshake"></use>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3 class="mp-stat-block__stat-title">Successful outcomes</h3>
      <div class="mp-stat-block__stat-cap">
        <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo <a href="/404/" title="404">consequat</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="position:absolute; width: 0; height: 0">
<symbol viewBox="0 0 85 85" id="icon-handshake"><path d="M68.956 8.487l-6.322-6.322A7.47 7.47 0 0 0 57.375 0H27.253a7.499 7.499 0 0 0-5.26 2.165l-6.321 6.322H0v33.96h8.5a4.235 4.235 0 0 0 4.237-4.21h1.208l11.236 10.147c4.104 3.333 9.802 3.413 14.025.504C40.866 50.323 42.66 51 44.665 51c2.417 0 4.688-.983 6.481-3.188a7.45 7.45 0 0 0 8.5-2.23l3.48-4.29a7.285 7.285 0 0 0 1.447-3.055h7.69a4.244 4.244 0 0 0 4.237 4.21H85V8.487H68.956zM6.375 38.197c-1.169 0-2.125-.956-2.125-2.125s.956-2.125 2.125-2.125 2.125.956 2.125 2.125a2.123 2.123 0 0 1-2.125 2.125zm51.797-.917l-3.467 4.277a1.071 1.071 0 0 1-1.5.16L50.03 39.14l-3.984 4.847c-.797.97-1.992.638-2.39.32l-4.888-4.184-2.072 2.55c-1.846 2.27-5.206 2.616-7.344.876L16.429 31.862H12.75V14.848h5.565l8.194-8.18c.266-.107.492-.2.757-.306h7.53l-5.139 4.715a9.504 9.504 0 0 0-.584 13.453c1.965 2.152 8.128 5.472 13.48.585l1.09-.996 14.37 11.66c.451.373.517 1.05.159 1.501zm14.078-5.418h-9.19a7.492 7.492 0 0 0-1.023-1.023l-13.64-11.076 1.66-1.515c.863-.796.93-2.138.133-3.001l-1.448-1.554a2.135 2.135 0 0 0-3.001-.133l-7.332 6.72c-1.261 1.156-3.413 1.249-4.595 0a3.15 3.15 0 0 1 .16-4.502l8.712-7.982a5.286 5.286 0 0 1 3.586-1.394l11.116-.027c.28 0 .545.106.73.305l8.195 8.182h5.937v17zm6.375 6.335c-1.169 0-2.125-.956-2.125-2.125s.956-2.125 2.125-2.125 2.125.956 2.125 2.125a2.123 2.123 0 0 1-2.125 2.125z"></path></symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please try using viewBox="0 -17 85 85"  for the symbol id="icon-handshake". Also you may try  viewBox="0 0 85 51" where 51 is the real height of the handshake. Do not forget to add a width and height for the <use> like <use width="85" height="85"...